# StringDictionary not serialized properly when edited through a custom editor in the winform designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I'm creating a user control with a StringDictionary property. I'm displaying a custom editor for this propery in the control property grid with the following code :

```
public partial class SomeUserControl : UserControl
{
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Editor("System.Diagnostics.Design.StringDictionaryEditor,System.Design", "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor, System.Drawing")]
    public StringDictionary Items { get; set; }

    public SomeUserControl()
    {
        Items = new StringDictionary();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The designer appears correctly in the winform designer when I click on the property. However, when I edit the values they are not serialized in the form.

Am I missing something? Or is it not supported by the StringDictionaryEditor?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you modify the Items and then alter another property, thus causing it to regenerate the code, does it then work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Thanks for the idea though !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StringDictionary does not implement **IList** and **ICollection** which are required for DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content to work.

Comment: Is there an alternative to StringDictionary with a builtin editor such as NameValueCollection? And if there is, what would be the matching editor?